# Shared footer between different pages (When using data-role="page" in JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a shared div footer that all his interior elements have to be the same for both pages.

```
 <div id="page1"  data-role="page">

 </div>

 <div id="page2"  data-role="page">

 </div>

 <div id="bar" data-role="footer" class="sharedSlideBar">

 </div>
```

Later on I will change the page1 using $.mobile.navigate('#page2') and I wan't to keep 
the functionality and the styles of the pages to the shared div footer (#bar)
How is it possible?

Comment: how is what possible?

Comment: Not sure about jquery, but if you care only about content (the class stay the same?) than in css (3) .classFooter:before{content attr(data-content) may be resonable alternative (and data-content attribute may be changed with any js)

Comment: your (Gaurav) solution to split the code into 2 html files is not what I want. I just wan't to save the styles of the data-role page

Answer (score 1):

jQuery mobile have two page templates.

One have every page placed inside a single HTML file, like in your case. It is also called multipage template.

Second one have 1 page per 1 HTML file. And it is called multi-HTML template.

Read more about them [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/multipage-template-vs-multi-html-template-in-jquery-mobile/).

What you need is a multi-HTML template. Here a working example:

#### HTML 1 - index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index",function () {
            $(document).on('click', "#changePage",function () {     
                $.mobile.changePage('second.html', { dataUrl : "second.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });
            }); 
        }); 

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#second",function () {
            var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
            parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
            alert(parameter);
        });         
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
          <a data-role="button" id="changePage">Javascript change page example</a>
                      <a href="second.html" data-transition="slide">Direct link button</a>
        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

#### HTML 2 - second.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">

        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

There's one more thing you need to know. Only first HTML file can have more then one inner **`data-role="page"`**. Every other HTML page can have ONLY 1 **`data-role="page"`** inside. Reason for this is described **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**. If you need more information just give me a comment.

Comment: I believe he wants to keep using the multi-page template. I'd also like to know how to do it in just one HTML file, since I'm creating a small Cordova app that would benefit from loading all pages in one pass.